# Read a word in XML between elements using sed command

Tags: sed, grep, xml

I want to read a word between two xml elements using `sed` command.

For e.g. in below xml, I want to read the number 1234567.

```
 <ns1:account>
    <ns2:name>Corporation</ns2:name>
    <address>
        <StrtNm>NewYork</StrtNm>
        <BldgNb>3</BldgNb>
        <PstCd>230300</PstCd>
        <Ctry>USA</Ctry>
    </address>
</ns1:account>
<ns3:details>
<ns4:accnum>
    <ns5:info>
        <nd6:accnum>1234567</nd6:accnum>
    </ns5:info>
</ns4:accnum>
</ns3:details>
```

I was able to do this using a combination of `grep` and `sed` commands as below,

```
grep -oz '<.*details>\s*<.*accnum>\s*<.*info>\s*<.*accnum>[0-9]*</.*accnum>' test.xml |sed -n 's:.*<.*accnum>\(.*\)</.*accnum>.*:\1:p'
```

but I read that `grep -oz` is not good for performance since it treats the entire file as a single line. So I tried with two `sed` commands but it only works if the file is properly formatted as the one shown above. It doesn't work if the xml comes as a single line without pretty printing.
This is what I tried:

```
sed -n '/.*details>/,/<\/.*accnum>/p' test.xml |sed -n 's:.*<.*accnum>\(.*\)<.*accnum>:\1:p'
```

Challenges:

1. The file can come with or without namespace prefixes in the elements.
2. The file is pretty large, about 100Mb or more.
3. The file contents can come as a properly formatted xml or as the entire xml as a single line.

I haven't tried `awk` command yet since there are existing scripts in our application which use the commands listed above, and I was hoping to get the same working.

Comment: Would it be reasonable to say that you want to extract the value for the `nd6:accnum` element?

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes correct

Comment: "_The file contents can come as a properly formatted xml or as the entire xml as a single line_". XML can be properly formatted as a single line. The two halves of your sentence are not opposites.

Answer (score 2):

I've had to edit your XML to make it a well-formed document (adding the `<root/>` element and declaring the namespaces):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:ns1="urn:ns1" xmlns:ns2="urn:ns2" xmlns:ns3="urn:ns3" xmlns:ns4="urn:ns4" xmlns:ns5="urn:ns5" xmlns:nd6="urn:nd6">
  <ns1:account>
    <ns2:name>Corporation</ns2:name>
    <address>
      <StrtNm>NewYork</StrtNm>
      <BldgNb>3</BldgNb>
      <PstCd>230300</PstCd>
      <Ctry>USA</Ctry>
    </address>
  </ns1:account>
  <ns3:details>
    <ns4:accnum>
      <ns5:info>
        <nd6:accnum>1234567</nd6:accnum>
      </ns5:info>
    </ns4:accnum>
  </ns3:details>
</root>
```

Having done that I can use `xmlstarlet` to parse the XML file and extract precisely the element you need

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//nd6:accnum' -n x.xml
1234567
```

You can modify the XPath to be more precise, as necessary. For example `/root/ns3:details/ns4:accnum/ns5:info/nd6:accnum` would be an extreme option.

If you don't have `xmlstarlet` available I strongly recommend you install it. If the system is not yours to manage, make it a prerequisite of the project you're on. Trying to parse an XML file with `sed` and `awk` will work in the short-term but it's setting up technical debt down the road, particularly if you have little control over the precise layout of the XML document (whitespace, newlines, comments, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Using xidel and a valid xml input (see @roaima answer), we can:

```
xidel   -se  '//nd6:accnum/text()'  file.xml
```

where

- `//nd6:accnum/text()` is a XPath expression meant to -- look for element "nd6:accnum" anywhere and select its text.

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner perl command will print the expected result:

```
perl -lne 'print "$1" if /<nd6:accnum>(\w+)</' file.xml
1234567
```